# scala add all the map values of a key to a queue

Tags: scala, dictionary, queue, breadth-first-search

i'm currently Learning how to implement a small breadth first algorithm. I want to add the values (neighbors) of "you" to a search queue.
The " += " operation does not work.. any idea how to solve this?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

// creating a hash table (allowing to set a map of key, value)
val graph = Map("you" -> ("bob", "claire", "alice"), "alice" -> ("peggy"), "bob" -> ("peggy", "anuj"), "claire" -> ("jonny", "thom"))

graph("bob") // prints the neighbors of "bob"
var search_queue = new Queue[]()
search_queue += graph("you")
println(search_queue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First, your `graph` **Map** goes from a **String** *key*, to a **tuple** of *values*. but since your tuples have different sizes, the compiler ends up inferring `java.io.Serializable` - I would use a **List** or other collection for the values.

Second you can use the [`empty` constructor](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Queue$.html#empty[A]:CC[A]), instead of `new` to instantiate the `search_queue`.

Third, if you want to add multiple values to a mutable collection you can use the [`++=` operator](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Queue.html#++=(xs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[A]):Growable.this.type), instead of looping each value and using `+=`.

Fourth, you only need the collection to be mutable, not the reference to it - thus you can use a `val`.

Maybe this code can help you.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

val graph = Map(
  "you" -> List("bob", "claire", "alice"),
  "alice" -> List("peggy"),
  "bob" -> List("peggy", "anuj"),
  "claire" -> List("jonny", "thom")
)

val searchQueue = Queue.empty[String]

searchQueue ++= graph.getOrElse("you", List.empty[String])
// searchQueue = Queue(bob, claire, alice)
```